# Applying a condition to rows of a 2d array

Tags: numpy, permutation

Consider `a = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])`

In the multiset `a`, there are exactly 2 instances each of 0,1,2, and 3.

I want to find all permutations of `a` that meet a condition as we move through each row from left to right:

**condition:**  **the 1st instance of 0,1,2, and 3 must appear in that order**, though they do not need to be consecutive.

`[0, 1,  , 2,  , 3,  ,  ]`  is ok,   `[0, 1,  , 3,  , 2,  ,  ]` is not ok

The 2nd instance of each number may appear anywhere in the row as long as it is after (to the right of) the 1st instance.

`[0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3]`  is ok

I've started by finding all 8!/2**4 = 2525 permutations of the multiset `a`:

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])

resultList = []
for p in multiset_permutations(a):
    resultList.append(p)
    
out = np.array(resultList)
```

My difficulty is that I'm drowning in the details when I try to set the condition. To compound the problem, the actual array `a` could have up to 5 pairs of values. **QUESTION:** How can the condition be written so that I can eliminate, from array `out`, all permutation rows that do not satisfy the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know your array consists of exactly pairs of the elements in `np.arange(4)`, you can use `np.argmax` to check:

```
max_values = np.max(a)
uniques = np.arange(max_values + 1)
# or you can just do
# uniques = np.unique(a)

resultList = []
for p in multiset_permutations(a):
    idx = np.argmax(p==uniques[:,None], axis=1)
    if (idx[:-1] < idx[1:]).all():
        resultList.append(p)
```

Then `resultList` would contains `420` permutations for `4` pairs; and `4725` for `5` pairs.

Comment: That is an excellent and clearly explained answer.   In the next separate step, I was going to apply a 2nd condition to your code's output.  The condition is:  Permutation rows can not have any consecutive values.  Is it possible to add this condition to the for loop in your code?  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I do notice a problem with some of the output rows.   Starting with row 226, for example, we have rows that start with  [0, 3, ...]  But, the condition states that the 1st instances of 0 1,2, and 3 MUST be in THAT ORDER, though they don't have to be consecutive.  So, both a 1 and a 2 would have to be found in the row after the 0 but before we get to the 1st 3.

Comment: @user109387 I found the bug, it should be `unquies = np.arange(max_values + 1)` or just `uniques = np.unique(a)` works.

Comment: Works beautifully.  Thank you for taking the time.  If you have any thoughts about my first comment, I'd be interested.

Comment: That condition would be `(p[1:]!=p[:-1]).all()`

Comment: That's exactly what I've been trying, but I get the error:  'bool' object has no attribute 'all'.   The relevant code lines are:

for p in multiset_permutations(a):
    if (p[1:]!=p[:-1]).all():  
        resultList.append(p)

I feel that I'm missing something obvious

Comment: apparently `p` is just a Python list, not a numpy array. Use `if np.allclose(p[1:], p[:-1]): resultList.append(p)`

Comment: Thank you for that response.   I just noticed the same thing - so this also works fine:<br>
if (np.array(p[1:])!=np.array(p[:-1])).all():